# 16GB vs 32GB Speed - Samsung Galaxy Tab S 10.5

Tags: samsung, tablet, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-10.5

So I was going to buy the [Samsung Galaxy Tab S 10.5](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab/SM-T800NZWAXAR) in the 16GB version. It is expandable up to an additional 128GB through MicroSD so I'm not too worried about space. My question though is will this tablet perform slower as it fills up with Apps and the Android OS?

I will save all pictures and videos in the SD card, but didn't know if the native apps and OS will bog down the small hard drive and cause lag... So in summation my question is:

Will the 16GB version of the tablet work slower than the 32GB due to space?

Comment: I am pretty sure just like any storage device. The main thing is, when they are almost full, the first thing to go out the window is the read/write times. So keeping your device almost full all the time could in theory slow it down. I try to clean up my phone once it hits about 66% full. Dont remember where I saw it, but I remember reading on XDA that the read/write speeds become really apparent around 80% full. But your mileage may vary. I think it depends on the device and how it handles the data.

Comment: Yeah thats a good call. I just don't know how fast I will fill 10gig. the 32gb version may be worth he extra $50...

Comment: Well that's up to you. I know everyone's use case is different, but I have the 16gb model Nvidia Shield tablet and I dont run into storage issues. But I also have a 64gb m.sd card that stores the bulk of my stuff. And yeah thats the downside to Samsung, They use so much space for touch wiz. Could always install a custom rom and regain some of that space they use.

Comment: That is cool info. How much do your apps take up on your tablet?

Comment: I normally have between 4-6gb free, on the device. Since there are a few apps/games that just seem to run better on the main storage instead of being on the SD card.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I got a couple good coupons at the end of the day and went with the 32gb just to be safe. It's for my wife and her business so I can see that filling up quick. Ended up only being $325 for an open box. Thanks.

Comment: Not bad. Here's to it working out for ya.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is so slight though that the difference will be unnoticeable, but the larger hard drive will be faster.

As requested:

http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/understanding-hard-drive-performance,1557-10.html

In addition to the statement at the top in several diagrams you can see that hard drives with the same specs but different sizes have faster read and write times as the size goes up for a majority of the tests.

Comment: Thanks, in that link you sent some of the larger HDD actually performed slower than some of the smaller ones. There was also smaller ones that performed slower than the larger ones. It was a cool artical though but doesn't seem like it will make much of a difference.

Comment: Like I said the difference won't be noticeable at all.  The majority of the tested drives that were bigger preformed faster, but you won't be able to be able to get specs like speed from what ever drive is in the device.  The speed of the hard drive should not make a difference in your decision when looking at devices like tablets.

Comment: Android devices don't use disc-based HDD storage, but they use flash-based storage instead. Without clarifying if the performance of flash memory is similar to HDD, the comparison doesn't look that useful to the readers.